# System does not print stderr

Tags: ruby, shell

I have the following Ruby code:

```rb
system "clang test.c -o test"
system "./test"
```

When I execute the above Ruby code, the stdout is printed, but the stderr is not.

When I run `clang test.c -o test && ./test` from the terminal, I get a `segmentation fault`, but the Ruby script does not print this.

How can I get the Ruby script to print all output from the system command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output "segmentation fault" is not printed by your test program itself. If you see this in your shell, it is in fact printed by the shell itself as a result of your program segfaulting.

Ruby does not print this. You can check the return code of your program after the `system` call returned however using the `$?` variable which contains a [`Process::Status` object](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Process/Status.html).

Here, you can e.g. check for [`signaled?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Process/Status.html#method-i-signaled-3F) to check if the process aborted due to a signal and then get this signal with the [`termsig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Process/Status.html#method-i-termsig) method. The signal number for a segmentation fault is `11`.

With your example, this could look like this:

```
system "./test"
# => false

$?.success?
# => nil

$?.signaled?
# => true

$?.termsig
# => 11
```